# C - Makefile missing separator

Tags: makefile

Hello I am trying to make a 'makefile' here's my code .

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra -I.
LFLAGS =
TARGET = algo2
SRC=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJ=$(SRC:.c=.o)
all : $(TARGET)
$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
$(CC) $^ $(LFLAGS) -o $@
%.o : %.c
$(CC) $^ $(GFLAGS) $< -c
clean :
$(RM) $(OBJ) *~ algo1
```

But i got this error "*** missing separator.Stop." .
I am a beginner and i don't know what is wrong with this thanks .

Comment: indent commands with tabs

Comment: Is that the simplest makefile you could think of?